# Calling Enum from another class

Tags: java, enums

This might be a little too basic question. I have tried the ways already given but its not working.
I want to call an ENUM from another class.

```
   package com.blackjack.game.cards;
public enum Card implements Comparable<Card> {

    ACE(1, 11),
    KING(13, 10),
    QUEEN(12, 10),
    JACK(11, 10),
    TEN(10, 10),
    NINE(9, 9),
    EIGHT(8, 8),
    SEVEN(7, 7),
    SIX(6, 6),
    FIVE(5, 5),
    FOUR(4, 4),
    THREE(3, 3),
    TWO(2, 2);

    public final int rank;
    public final int value;
    private static final String[] CARD_NAMES = {
            "joker", "ace", "two", "three",
            "four", "five", "six", "seven",
            "eight", "nine", "ten", "jack",
            "queen", "king"
    };

    private Card(final int rank, final int value) {
        this.rank = rank;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getRank() {
        return rank;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
```

I am doing it in the following way but it's not working.

`import com.blackjack.game.cards.Card;
Card card = new Card.ACE;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java You don't need to use new to access the enum value:

```
Card card = Card.ACE;
```

Another note: 
Since you have public getters, why to not use private fields:

```
 private final int rank;
 private final int value;
```

And yet another note, it looks like CARD_NAMES are not used anywhere and they're private.

The enum can contain the name in a String field:

```
private final int rank;
private final int value;
private final String name;

public String getName() {return name;}
```

When you create an enum:

```
ACE(1, 11, "ace"),
KING(13, 10, "king")
....
```

Alternatively, you can access the names of created Enums via built-in `name()` method; here is an example:

```
String name = Card.ACE.name();
```